# How to create a list of non-empty dataframes names?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have created a list of dataframe and want to run a loop through the list to run some manipulation on some of those dataframes. Note that although this is a list I have manually created, but this dataframes exist in my code.

```py
df_list = [df_1, df_2, df_3, df_4, df_5, ...]

list_df_matching = []
list_non_matching = []
```

Most of these dataframes are blank. But 2 of them will have some records in them. I want to find the name of those dataframes and create a new list - list_non_matching

```py
for df_name in df_list:
    q = df_name.count()
    if q > 0:
        list_non_matching.append(df_name)
    else:
        list_df_matching.append(df_name)
```

My goal is to get a list of dataframe names like [df_4, df_10], but I am getting the following:

```py
[DataFrame[id: string, nbr: string, name: string, code1: string, code2: string],
 DataFrame[id: string, nbr: string, name: string, code3: string, code4: string]]
```

Is the list approach incorrect? Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example to illustrate one way to do it with the help of [empty](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html) property and Python built-in function [globals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals):

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [2, 4], "col2": [5, 9]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["col1", "col2"])
df4 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [3, 8], "col2": [2, 0]})
df5 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [], "col2": []})

df_list = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]
```

```py
list_non_matching = [
    name
    for df in df_list
    for name in globals()
    if not df.empty and globals()[name] is df
]
```

```py
print(list_non_matching)
# Output
['df2', 'df4']
```

Comment: This is a correct solutios based on my problem definition "non-empty". However to be precise, the data frames are not going be entirely empty, they will have column names but no rows. Basically those data frames will be generated as a result of an operation which will return zero records - this can be replicated by running the following.

column_names = ["col1", "col2"]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)

So when I run the above code it still returns all 5 data frames . Not just df2 and df4. Any suggestions how to fix it ?

Comment: Hi, I can't reproduce your issue : I have modified examples in my answer to show that, even if a column header is passed to the dataframe constructor, df.empty still returns true, and only df2 and df4 are returned. Are you sure the dataframes in your real use case are empty, besides the column names?

Comment: Yes. The data frames have only header (i.e. column names) but no rows. Its because they are generated from a sql query which returns non matching values. when there are no non matching values then the data frame has zero rows

Comment: I am getting the right result now. Thanks.